# Error: argument "time_intervals" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the audpc value from disease data over time. But the function wil not run           because argument is missing but if I print the argument values are there. '

```
'# separate the date row and the header row into two separate data frames'
date_row <- convertToDate(data[1, 4:ncol(data)])
header_row <- data[2, 1:13]
colnames(data) <- c("", "", "", paste0("Day.", 1:length(date_row)))

'# exclude the first two rows of the data frame'
data_numeric <- data[-c(1:2), c(4:13)]
data_numeric <- apply(data_numeric, 2, as.numeric)

'# subset start_time and end_time to match the length of data_numeric'
start_date <- as.Date(date_row[1], format="%d-%m-%Y")
time_intervals <- difftime(as.Date(date_row[-1], format="%d-%m-%Y"), start_date, units="days")
time_intervals <- as.numeric(time_intervals)
'# convert start_date to a date object'
start_date <- as.Date(start_date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

'# convert end_date to character vector'
end_date <- as.character(end_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date <- start_date + days(time_intervals)
print(time_intervals)

'# calculate AUPDC and StAUDPC'
audpc <- function(x, start_date, time_intervals) {
  auc <- 0
  for (i in 2:length(x)) {
    auc <- auc + (time_intervals[i] - time_intervals[i-1]) * ((x[i-1] + x[i])/2)
  }
  return(auc)
}


aupdc_vec <- c(NA, NA, apply(data_numeric, 1, function(x) audpc(x, time_intervals)))

'# add AUPDC and StAUDPC to data frame'
data$AUPDC <- aupdc_vec

'I am new to coding and don't know what the try with this error'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function audpc:

```
audpc <- function(x, start_date, time_intervals) {
  auc <- 0
  for (i in 2:length(x)) {
    auc <- auc + (time_intervals[i] - time_intervals[i-1]) * ((x[i-1] + x[i])/2)
  }
  return(auc)
}
```

Takes three inputs: `x`, `start_date` and `time_intervals`.
None of them have default values.

In this line:

```
aupdc_vec <- c(NA, NA, apply(data_numeric, 1, function(x) audpc(x, time_intervals)))
```

The section `audpc(x, time_intervals)` will call audpc with `x = x` and `start_date = time_intervals` because those are the first two arguments.  You need to also explicitly supply the `start_date`.  It's sometimes also useful to specify the arguments by name:

```
aupdc_vec <- c(NA, NA, apply(data_numeric,
                             1,
                             function(x) audpc(x = x,
                                               start_date = start_date, 
                                               time_intervals =  time_intervals)))
```

Comment: thanks for the realy quick answer. the problem however was that the time interval did not had 0 at the begining. so I added the 0 to time_interval and updated the code like this   audpc <- function(x, time_intervals) {
    auc <- 0
    for (i in 2:length(x)) {
      auc <- auc + (time_intervals[i] - time_intervals[i-1]) * ((x[i-1] + x[i])/2)
    }
    return(auc)
  }
  
  aupdc_vec <- c(NA, NA, apply(data_numeric, 1, function(x) audpc(x, time_intervals)))       now it works